# Top 5 (MAX) values in mschart

Tags: c#, mschart

I have made a chart with MSchart, how do I show the top 5 (MAX) values of mi datatable in the chart.

My chart shows 18 rows I want to show only 5 rows ordered by values (desc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a DataTable that has an "x" and a "y" column, and you want to chart the x and y values for the 5 largest values of y, you could use a DataView to sort your DataTable, then loop through the five rows and put them in the chart:

```
// assuming dt is your DataTable with an "x" and "y" column
var dv = new DataView(dt);
dv.Sort = "y desc";

for (int count = 0; count < 5; count++ )
{
    chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(dv[count][0], dv[count][1]);
}
```

### Edit

There might be a simpler way to do this.  Just add all your data as you normally would, then use the DataManipulator:

```
chart1.DataManipulator.FilterTopN(5, "SeriesName");
```

I hadn't used that until today, but it seems to do exactly what you're after.

Comment: Doesn't c# also provide a for loop?

Comment: You can use an index to iterate over a DataView. See my edits.

Comment: Thanks for that @nunespascal.  It looks much better now!